# How to get the value from interface and use it on another function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I cant get the value of `userType` to use it on conditional satatement.

UserType:

```
const RadioForm = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <label>Customer</label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                value="Customer"
                checked={props.userType === "Customer"}
                onChange={(e) => {props.setUserType(e.target.value)}}
            />

            <br />

            <label>Vendor</label>
            <input
                type="radio"
                value="Vendor"
                checked={props.userType === "Vendor"}
                onChange={(e) => {props.setUserType(e.target.value)}}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Login Page:

```
interface LoginCardProps {
  userType: string;
  setUserType: string;
}

const LoginCard: React.FC<LoginCardProps> = props => {
  const {userType, setUserType } = props;

   return (
    <RadioForm
       userType={userType}
       setUserType={setUserType}
     />
    )
```

**What Im trying to achieve:**

I will use the `userType` variable to use it in conditional statement.

```
const GetUserType: LoginCardProps = {
  if (userType === "Customer") {
    return <Customer />
  }
  else if (userType === "Vendor") {
    return <Vendor/>
  }
}
```

But i always get this error:

This condition will always return 'false' since the types '{ if(userType: any): any; }' and 'string' have no overlap.

> Answer by @Raja

```
const GetUserType = ({userType}: LoginCardProps) => {
        if (userType === "Customer") {
          return <Customer />
        } else if (userType === "Vendor") {
          return <Vendor/>
        }
      }
```

Thank you for clearing it to me. but i got a new error

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'LoginCardProps': userType, setUserType
```

I already define it in Login:

```
const [userType, setUserType] = useState("Admin");

  return (
    <LoginPage
      userType={userType}
      setUserType={setUserType}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you defined as object literal syntax with return kind of mistake, the expectation might GetUserType should be functional components and props type should LoginCardProps.

```
  const GetUserType = ({userType}: LoginCardProps) => {
        if (userType === "Customer") {
          return <Customer />
        } else if (userType === "Vendor") {
          return <Vendor/>
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you please update the question to reproduce the issue, I couldn't get that